# File.Copy Access Denied

Tags: c#, file-io, copy, .net

I have a problem with copying from local disk to flash. The code worked before, but after I create anoteher foreach loop and I had to create new objects, the File.Copy functionality isn't working anymore.
In value File | System.IO.File there are values like: Error_Access_Denied | 5, Error_Invalid Parameter| 87, GetFileExInfoStandard | 0.

edit: locationUSB present file path on flash. (locationUSB == "D:\something.hex") and x._location == "C:\something_1.hex" .

```
foreach (object item in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    versionOnDisk = this.VersionInt(x._version);
    versionOnFlash = this.VersionInt(((DataGridViewRow)item).Cells[2].Value.ToString());

    if (versionOnFlash > versionOnDisk)
        forbidCopying = true;
    else
        locationUSB = _logicalDrive + ((DataGridViewRow)item).Cells["Filename"].Value.ToString();  // <-- location value (because of the foreach)

    if (!forbidCopying)
        File.Copy(x._location, locationUSB, true);   // <--
    else if (AllowDelete.Checked)
        File.Delete(locationUSB);
}
```

edit:
If I change the location into logical drive path, which value is "D:\" I get the DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\'.

Comment: Access denied means you don't have sufficient rights. Invalid parameter means one of the parameters was invalid. Only you know what parameters you are passing. We can't guess.

Comment: do you have rights on that location you are trying to copy the file? I think that is the issue. Open that location in explorer and try to create a text file. If it doesn't allow you then for sure you don't have rights to that location.

Comment: also check that location is valid or not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm passing full file paths. 
Faisal: I have all rights and also the location is valid

Comment: You say that this code worked before, so the cause of the problem is not here (barring permission exceptions). I will look for changes in the code that checks the version info on the USB. Perhaps something changed there and you leave your files on USB locked.

Comment: Additional tips: Look into [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx](Path.Combine()) to add paths together, and don't use fields directly (make them private then wrap their value in get/set properties)

Comment: But do you have a disk D: pointing to your USB sticks or not?

Comment: All these errors point to the same culprit. Lacking of permissions on the destination.

Comment: @Steve: I tried with another flash drive and also on hard drive location, but it is the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably after creating new files, you are not closing the `FileStream`s. Close the `FileStream`s of the newly created files using either `myFile.Close();` or create new files inside `using (var myFile = File.Create(myPath))` blocks.

Comment: can you provide the whole code and exact exception and where it occurs?